# nested list view bind problem c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, nested

i have list view inside another list view  like lv1-->lv2 now problem is inserting record in nested list view see error...

**Inserting is not supported by data source 'SqlDataSource2' unless InsertCommand is specified.**

another problem when i keep datasource2 in LV1 selected template but datasource2 is not binding lv2.. how can bind lv2...?

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind second listview in first listview row databound event like:

In first listview databound event, first you need to finding the second listview control and then bind the second listview

hope this help.

Comment: yesss its find on itmetemplete but i want on selected template how can find nestedlist view (vl2) and also ds2

Comment: you may find in this way in first list row databound event: if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.SelectedItem){// then find the control over here}

Comment: there is no row databoud just 2 mathod databound and itemdatabound

Comment: then dear use itemdatabound event. rowdatabound used in grid. and find the control in if condition which i have written above. you need to find the control in this way : DataList _DL=(DataList)e.Item.FindControl("DataList2ID Place Here")

Comment: protected void lv1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource ds = (SqlDataSource)e.Item.FindControl("SqlDataSource2");
        var lv2 = (ListView)e.Item.FindControl("lv2");
        lv2.DataSource = ds;
        lv2.DataBind();
    }

Comment: there is no findcontril but when i keep lv2 on  lv1 nested item template than this mathod foun but when i keep on selected item template lv2 not found

Comment: you need to put the code in this condition:if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.SelectedItem){SqlDataSource ds = (SqlDataSource)e.Item.FindControl("SqlDataSource2"); var lv2 = (ListView)e.Item.FindControl("lv2"); lv2.DataSource = ds; lv2.DataBind(); }

Comment: yes but there is only three prperties dataitem, emptyitem,insertitem

Comment: there is no ListItemType.SelectedItem

Comment: please use datalist itemdatabound event. all properyies are their { if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.SelectedItem) {}}

Comment: no i m not using datalist i need listview and inside nested listview and inside list veiw

Comment: datalist also support itemdatabound dear